# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox open url error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, perl

Am using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox in perl to automate a process. I can login without hassle by supplying the required fields and posting to the URL.

URL: `hxxp://www.somesite.com/login-link.php`

The above URL changes upon successful login to

```
hxxp://www.somesite.com/app/default.php
```

When I follow on any link, the URL doesn't change, but the content div would. When you open the link directly on the browser it i.e hxxp://www.somesite.com/app/profile.php?id=3 it doesn't load the parent div/frame which is hxxp://www.somesite.com/app/default.php.

My question is that, is it possible to get($url2) whilst maintaining/keeping the parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue for anyone interested I used the EVAL function to achieve this